# Scale and multiscale space Theory

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science

First of all this Theory confuse me could someone explain it for me in some words.?
also the word scale in computer vision context does it  means the various size of objects 
Or the various units measurement of objects ( i.e meter , cm etc) or what I think is the various degrees  smoothing/blurring for the same interesting Image  ?

Second  making multi-scale of Image  by using  smooth/blur operator which one I know the Gaussian blur operator. why they do a numbers of Smoothing for  the Same Image  , what the point of making numbers of smooth Images with different details/resolution but not different in size for the same scene (i.e one smooth operator on the interest image with size 256X256 and another time with 512X512 ).
I'm talking in context of Features extraction & description .
I will be thankful if some one could clarify the subject for me sorry for my Language !.

Comment: Your question is too broad for [so], and would probably be a better fit for [cs.se] anyway. Check their help centre before you post there since in its current form it may be too broad there too.

Comment: I'll write an answer.  This actually should go on Signal Processing exchange: http://dsp.stackexchange.com, but eh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Scale" here alludes to both the size of the image as well as the size of the objects themselves... at least for current feature detection algorithms.  The reason why you construct a scale space is because we can focus on features of a particular size depending on what scale we are looking at.  The smaller the scale, the coarser or smaller features we can concentrate on.  Similarly, the larger the scale, the finer or larger features we can concentrate on.

You do all of this on the same image because this is a common pre-processing step for feature detection.  The whole point of feature detection is to be able to detect features over multiple scales of the image.  You only output those features that are reliable over all of the different scales.  This is actually the basis of the [Scale-Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) where one of the objectives is to be able to detect keypoints robustly that can be found over multiple scales of the image.

What you do to create multiple scales is decompose an image by repeatedly subsampling the image and blurring the image with a Gaussian filter at each subsampled result.   This is what is known as a [scale space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space).  A typical example of what a scale space looks like is shown here:

[image]

The reason why you choose a Gaussian filter is fundamental to the way the scale space works.  At each scale, you can think of each image produced as being a more "simplified" version of the one found from the previous scale.  With typical blurring filters, they introduce new spurious structures that don't correspond to those simplifications made in the finer scales.  I won't go into the details, but there is a whole bunch of scale space theory where in the end, scale space construction using the Gaussian blur is the most fundamental way to do this, because new structures are not created when going from a fine scale to any coarse scale.  You can check out that Wikipedia article I linked you to above that talks about the scale space for more details.

---

Now, traditionally a scale space is created by convolving your image with a Gaussian filter of various standard deviations, and that Wikipedia article has a nice pictorial representation of that.  However, when you look at more recent feature detection algorithms like SURF or SIFT, they use a combination of blurring using different standard deviations as well as subsampling the image, which is what I talked about at the beginning of this post.

Either way, check out that Wikipedia post for more details.  They talk about about this stuff more in depth than what I've done here.

Good luck!

Comment: wow! that's why i Like humankind they can explain in great way .
I'm very grateful for you thanks a lot .